# Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.sse4.2 [bit 20]

Tags: android

i want to see my output in android studio with emulator.i use AVD but it show me this error.whats this error mean?how i can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use a `CPU`, which supports the `SSE4.2` instruction set; eg. `Nehalem` or newer - else you can only run `x86` images, which is perfectly fine for testing. I use them for performance reasons, even if I could run `x86_64` images. `ARM64` hardware is what actually matters for testing, these days.

This question should probably disclose, which `CPU` you are even using, which might be an outdated `CPU`, considering the initial release date of the `Nehalem` architecture, which introduced `SSE4.2`.

For reference: [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005779/processors.html).